# application.properties versus applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a running spring boot sample application with the configuration for Hibernate and else stored in the `application.properties` file.

Reading through the docs I am wondering where the `applicationContext.xml` comes in place? Is this encapsulated by `@SpringBootApplication`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationContext.xml` contains bean definitions and relations, `application.properties` is just for general system configuration.

Normally you would go the Annotation / Java based configuration but if you happen to have some legacy beans xml config that you would like to use, then you would normally place it under:

```
src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml
```

and then create a class with appropriate configuration annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class LegacyXmlConfiguration {}
```

just make sure that this class is part of the spring boot's packages to scan.

Comment: So, do I get it correct. The SpringBootApplication Annotaion, which contains the Configuration Annotaion automatically takes the config properties from application.properties ?

Comment: or application.yml by default yes